# SQL query to search for matches within derived table

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables. The first table ("MainTable") contains rows with data and a primary key (call it "MainKey"). The second two tables contain two columns each.

The first child table, "StatesTable", contains a unique combination of an ID (matches "MainKey") and a column, "State", which is the abbreviated value of a state (i.e., WA, CA).

The second child table, "CategoriesTable", contains a unique combination of an ID (matches "MainKey") and a column, "Category", which is various categories (i.e., "Lawyer", "Engineer", "Teacher").

What I'm trying to achieve is to get all matches in "MainTable" for various posted queries of the two child tables. For instance, if a user selects three states (WA, CA, MT) and two categories ("Lawyer", "Engineer") then the query should return all matches in "MainTable" where the primary key matches that of the child tables.

I have the queries working for the child tables to retrieve a distinct result but I'm not certain how to use these derived tables in the main query to search for all matches of the primary MainKey "WITHIN" the derived table results.

Here is my query for the "States" child table as an example. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
SELECT DISTINCT MainKey
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM `StatesTable` 
    WHERE State IN ('WA','CA','MT')
) t
```

Comment: Do they have to be Lawyers/Engineers who are in one of WA/CA/MT, or Lawyers or Engineers anywhere or People who are in WA, CA or MT

Comment: If it was me, I'd delete this, read that (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) , and start over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want only Lawyers or Engineers who are in WA, CA, or MT, this query using two `IN` expressions should give you the results you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM MainTable
WHERE MainKey IN (SELECT DISTINCT MainKey 
                  FROM StatesTable 
                  WHERE State IN ('WA', 'CA', 'MT'))
  AND MainKey IN (SELECT DISTINCT MainKey 
                  FROM CategoriesTable 
                  WHERE Category IN ('Lawyer', 'Engineer'))
```

If you want people who are Lawyers or Engineers, OR who live in WA, CA or MT, just change the `AND` in the `WHERE` clause to `OR`.

Comment: I should have been more specific. The "MainTable" contains rows of information which have at least one state and category (or multiple) associated with them. The search query would then look for all rows from the MainTable where at least one match of a state or category in the sub tables is found.

Comment: @afk changing the `AND` to an `OR` should achieve that. Or I am completely misunderstanding you?

Comment: Nope, that works great, I was just overlooking it. Thanks for the help this makes the query make more sense now.